# EGit Conflict Resolution GUI?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I think I am just merely (coming from an SVN background) confused with how Git conflicts are handled by EGit within Eclipse.

I understand that it shows textually in the normal standard method by which to show conflicts as stated here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_how_conflicts_are_presented however it isn't very clean and with thousands of lines of code it becomes unmanageable to avoid accidently deleting lines that are not meant to be deleted.

Is there any GUI within EGit that can show me each conflict with an step over ability?

I have searched around and I heard about the `merge tool` however when I follow the instructions by right clicking on the top level node of the tree (i.e. right click `models` folder that has the `<>` type icon denoting a conflict, which has a conflicted file of `User.php` within it) the merge tool is greyed out.

Am I using the `merge tool` wrong?

### Edit

I found out that a bug can cause EGit merge tool to not show: [Why is the merge tool disabled in Eclipse for a EGit-managed project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934765/why-is-the-merge-tool-disabled-in-eclipse-for-a-egit-managed-project) however I am using EGit 1.3.0 so I should be way past this bug.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Merge Tool on the file directly? By the way, I would recommend using the Git Staging View (use Ctrl+3 to find it), where all conflicting files are directly available in the view.

Comment: @robinst Nice didn't know about git staging view thanks :), yea I have tried right clicking on the main project directory that shows the conflicts icon and it is still disabled. I have clicked on every folder/file that shows the icon, nothing :(

Comment: @robinst It is also disabled from the git staging view where is does show my conflicts as unstaged changes

Comment: Does your project have "MERGING" as the status (in the label to the right of the project)? I also recommend trying the newest version through the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/).

Comment: @robinst It did not. I checkedout my production branch in the git repo view, then right click on my dev branch and clicked merge, after that it showed the conflicts but didn't show MERGING next to the project in the explorer. Maybe I followed the process wrong? I am going to merge my production branch to my dev branch in the next couple of days on eclipse 4.2 with the latest git extension version, I'll see what happens.

Comment: Eh, sorry, it should say "Conflicts".

Comment: @robinst I can't remember that one actually, I'll have to take a look soon and see if it does. So if there are conflict icons on the files/folders the "status" (the thing in `[]` next to the project name in project explorer) should have "Conflicts" in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this question two days both here and on the EGit forums: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/371459/ unfortunately (even after everyone viewed it) no one had a real answer so I decided to solve my conflicts manually and just merge that way.

This way was, in reality, quicker and easier than trying to solve why the merge tools were not working for me, ironically.